# align toggled div directly below parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having a little trouble trying to get a toggled div to align directly below the parent. It seems to appear to the right and slightly over the top of the parent.

This will be for use on an editor toolbar, the the text editor stackoverflow and various forums use.

Unsure on the best and simplest way to solve it.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".editor-dropdown", function() {
  $('.editor-dropdown-content', this).toggle(); // p00f
});
```

```css
.editor-dropdown {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 14px;
}

.editor-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 900;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-dropdown">
  Header
  <b class="caret-down"></b>
  <div class="editor-dropdown-content">
    <span class="dropdown-option" data-tag="h1">H1</span> H2 H3 H4
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNQZzM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parent to `position: relative` then use `top/left` positioning to put the menu where you want it. If you want everything to align better, I would make the "header" text an element and apply the border/padding/etc to it and style the menu the same way set to `left: 0; top: 100%;` to left-align it and put it below "header"

```js
$(document).on('click', ".editor-dropdown", function()
{
 $('.editor-dropdown-content', this).toggle(); // p00f
});
```

```css
.editor-dropdown {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-header {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.editor-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 900;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-dropdown">
  <span class="dropdown-header">Header</span>
  <b class="caret-down"></b>
  <div class="editor-dropdown-content">
    <span class="dropdown-option" data-tag="h1">H1</span> H2 H3 H4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, doing that worked perfectly even without setting the "header" text into a span as well, but will keep that in mind, thanks! This solution did it perfectly, without forcing me to separate the content like others suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Please put "Header" text under span tag and give it a class like below:

```
<div class="editor-dropdown">
    <span class="dropdoanHeader">Header</span>
    <b class="caret-down"></b>
    <div class="editor-dropdown-content">
        <span class="dropdown-option" datatag="h1">H1</span>
        H2
        H3
        H4
    </div>
</div>
```

After that replace below css

```
.editor-dropdown
{
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.dropdoanHeader
{
    padding: 5px 14px;
}

.editor-dropdown-content
{
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the CSS like below

```
.editor-dropdown-content
{
display: none;
z-index: 900;
position:relative;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 5px 14px;
left: 60;
bottom: 100;
}
```

Was able to align it below header . Check the codepen below

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdoJKp

Comment: Sorry, that ends up keeping it inside the parent element, which ends up looking really weird.

Comment: Ooh sorry , misunderstood your question , you want it completely out of the header and aligned below it ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Okay , then all you got to do is to  remove the toggle div out of the parent in your HTML  and then use position:relative to align it relative to the parent in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```js
$(document).on('click', ".editor-dropdown", function()
{
 $('.editor-dropdown-content').toggle(); // p00f
});
```

```css
.editor-dropdown
{
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5px 14px;
  width: 200px;
}
.editor-dropdown-content
{
 display: none;
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 padding: 5px 14px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-dropdown">Header
 <b class="caret-down"></b>    
</div>
<div class="editor-dropdown-content">
 <span class="dropdown-option" data-tag="h1">H1</span>
     H2
     H3
     H4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `position: absolute;` to the `.editor-dropdown` and then `left: 0;` to `.editor-dropdown-content`.

[image]

However, better is probably to take the `.editor-dropdown-content` out of the `.editor-dropdown`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWBjpQ

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one?

HTML:

```
    <div class="editor-dropdown">
                Header
    <b class="caret-down"></b>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-dropdown-content">
        <span class="dropdown-option" data-tag="h1">H1</span>
        <span class="dropdown-option" data-tag="h1">H2</span>   
        <span class="dropdown-option" data-tag="h1">H3</span>           
        <span class="dropdown-option" data-tag="h1">H4</span>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.editor-dropdown
{
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 5px 14px;  
}
.editor-dropdown-content
{
display: none;
z-index: 900;
top: 40px;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 5px 14px;
}

.dropdown-option {
 display:block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', ".editor-dropdown", function()
{
$('.editor-dropdown-content').toggle(); // p00f
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKdjLJ